# Hyper-V - Minifilter to filter I/O operations on VHDX files

Tags: windows, driver, hyper-v, minifilter, filter-driver

I'm trying to write a minifilter to filter all I/O operations that are happening in the hard-disk files ie. VHDX files of each VM. As mentioned in  [this](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/cbt-change-block-tracking-simplified-himanshu-sonkar)  article, I've implemented a minifilter to capture all IRP_MJ_WRITE requests and have deployed it on the Hyper-V host. Howver, I'm able to filter write requests of all the files in the Hyper-V host except the VHDX files. For example, when I change a txt document in the Hyper-V host, I'm able to find a record in my minifilter. But when I do some changes in one of the VMs, the vhdx file in the host is modified but my minifilter is not capturing that change. I guess the write requests to VHDX file is different from normal write requests. What am I doing wrong? Am I missing anything?